# How do I find references of Redux state in the codebase?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

If I have a `rootReducer` that contains state for people `const rootReducer = combineReducers({ people: peopleReducer })` how do I find references to `people` in the codebase? We have a mix of react-redux hooks and `mapStateToProps`.

The underlying question is how do I know when I can remove a reducer and its associated actions and action creators?

One possible solution could be to search for occurrences using a regex. The best I've come up with so far is `(useSelector|mapStateToProps).*\((.|\n)*people.*\)`.